# How to query bazel for the full list of generated files that have the extension .srcjar.zip?

Tags: bazel

I'm working on a huge project with a huge bazel dependency graph.

When I run `bazel build ...`, I find lots of files in `bazel-out/` with the extension `.srcjar.zip`, in addition to a million files I'm not interested in.

I'm trying to craft a bazel command that builds just these `.srcjar.zip` files.

I studied [bazel queries](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html) but haven't found an example that demonstrates how to query for output files.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I imagine some combination of the [`filter`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#filter) and [`kind`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#kind) query functions can accomplish this:

```
$ bazel query 'filter('.*\.srcjar\.zip$', kind("generated file", //...:*))'
```